# HTML in PHP - displaying variables from MYSQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MYSQL table containing tournament data for players. Each player has stats like games_won, games_lost, etc. I am trying to display this information in a table.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
//Connecting to $db
//...

//Store table data into array
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM ladder");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['id'] . " " . <a href=$row['link']$row['username']</a> . " " . $row['tourney_wins'] . " " . $row['game_wins'] . " " . $row['game_losses'] . " " . $row['last_played'];
echo "<br>";
```

I get an error (Unexpected "<") on

```
<a href=$row['link']$row['username']</a>
```

I am trying to display each username in the table as a hyperlink to their respective profile on another site. Can anyone give me a correction? Thanks!

Comment: `echo $row['id'] . " " . <` <= right there I'll bet. You're missing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be quoted (assuming I interpreted how you wanted the link properly):

```
//Connecting to $db
//...

//Store table data into array
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM ladder");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo( $row['id']." <a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['username']."</a> ".$row['tourney_wins']." ".$row['game_wins']." ".$row['game_losses']." ".$row['last_played'] );
    echo("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<a href=$row['link']$row['username']</a>
```

to

```
"<a href=$row['link']$row['username']</a>"
```

Comment: You must quote your HTML php cant interpret <a that's why It gave a syntax error.

Comment: Yep that was it, knew it was something with quotes but couldn't remember where they go. Thanks to you and Marc B

Comment: One more question...and this one might need a new topic because it's a different problem. But now I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected " (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)" on the line we just changed.

Comment: Did u closed the HTML at </a>" with a quote ?

Comment: I did. ilovecode's submission fixed the Parse error

Comment: Yea I saw. There was some question with Quotes and appends.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote your html:

```
echo $row['id'] . " " . <a href=$row['link']$row['username']</a> . " " ...snip...
                       ^--here                                  ^--here
```

Since it's not quoted, PHP is interpreting it `<a` as `concatenate less than undefined constant 'a'`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Also the a tag needs a closing > after the link